# Write a simple program which can digest the api endpoint

Tags: javascript, json, endpoint

The endpoint is:
{"instructions":"write a program to solve the following math problem in the order of operations specified and print the result to a page, comma formatted","problem":{"variables":{"a":7,"b":2763,"c":932},"operations":"(a + b) - c"}}

The program should be able to solve and print the answer to the math problem contained within the JSON response of this api endpoint.

I am trying so hard to understand what it is asking for but failed to do so. Can anyone please help me with it. I am given this information and asked to solve it.
Please help!

Comment: Sounds like homework...

Comment: Its an interview question which is going far above my head.

Comment: It sounds like it's just asking you to add the a value to the b value, then subtract the c value from that...

Comment: It is a simple parsing problem. Many ways to solve it. Hopefully the company does not monitor stackoverflow....

Comment: Please help me with atleast one way. I would like to again make it clear. I am not giving interview. I am preparing for one . I would like to learn it so that I am prepared when such question comes up.

Comment: Maybe it helps to clarify with the interviewer whether the object IS the question, or the problem inside the object is the question. Is the focus on formatting, or parsing, or just getting the result?

Answer (score -2):

Disclaimer: I don't care that this solution is NOT an answer to this interview. I just want to show a snippet of code that can "work with" the provided object. The code might be missing the point of the interview, which is completely NOT my concern.

You may ignore the text description of the problem and evaluate the result of the expression:

```
var obj={"instructions":"...",
"problem":{"variables":{"a":7,"b":2763,"c":932},"operations":"(a + b) - c"}};

var vars=obj.problem.variables;

for (var k in vars) eval(k+'='+vars[k]);
console.log( eval(obj.problem.operations) );
```